# geolocation.getCurrentPosition() not working in Android mobiles

Tags: ionic4

`geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` is not working in Android mobiles, is this an Ionic bug? Or is there any better solution to achieve this?

```
  ngOnInit() {
            this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error getting location', error);
            });
            let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
            watch.subscribe((data) => {
                this.data = data;
                this.currentLat = data.coords.latitude;
                this.currentLng = data.coords.longitude;
                this.accuracy = data.coords.accuracy;
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue once and was able to solve it by enabling High Accuracy GPS on the mobile device.

You can use the Location Accuracy Plugin 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/location-accuracy 
to activate high accuracy mode when loading the application

```
import { LocationAccuracy } from '@ionic-native/location-accuracy/ngx';

constructor(private locationAccuracy: LocationAccuracy) { }

...

this.locationAccuracy.canRequest().then((canRequest: boolean) => {

    if(canRequest) { 
       this.locationAccuracy.request(this.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).then(
       () => console.log('Request successful'),
       error => console.log('Error requesting location permissions', error)
       );
    }

});
```

or you can simply pass

```
 this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ enableHighAccuracy : true, timeout: 10000 } )
```

Comment: How did you do this? Give examples

Comment: Thank you for editing your answer! With an example, readers can understand it better. "fuller explanations are better" [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the next values in the variable **options**

```
import { Geolocation, Geoposition } from '../../node_modules/@ionic-native/geolocation';

constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation)

...

 var options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    maximumAge: 0
    };

this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options)
  .then((result: Geoposition) => {
    console.log(result)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
});
```